# javascript promise rejects in two places

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I work with promise-based libraries such as `moment.js` and `axios`.
This time I want to create a promise by myself.

I have a function to send emails. Simply what I want is if there is no error resolve the promise and if there is an error reject the promise.

```js
export default async function password_reset_request(email, user_name, link) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {

            var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: 'gmail',
                auth: {
                    user: 'something@gmail.com',
                    pass: 'secret'
                }
            });

            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
                if (error) {
                    reject()
                } else {
                    resolve()
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            reject()
        }
    })
}
```

Is this technique correct? I am rejected for my promise in two places.

Comment: Yep, that looks right, if `createTransport` is synchronous (of course, also pass in the error into `reject` and the result into `resolve`)

Comment: I also recommend you reject with the error - `reject(error)`, it can be useful for debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues:

- You don't need an `async` function when you don't use `await`. Your function returns a promise already, so there is no need for `async`.
- There is no need to have a `try...catch` block inside a promise constructor callback function: if an exception occurs there it will automatically be converted to a rejection with the error as reason. NB: The same principle holds in a `then` callback.

The *promisifying* you did for `sendMail` is correct. It would be best practice to create a dedicated function for that alone (so without `createTransport`). It would also be good to pass useful information to `reject` and `resolve`:

```
function sendMailPromise(transporter, mailOptions) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
            return error ? reject(error) : resolve(info);
        });
    })
}

export default function password_reset_request(email, user_name, link) {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'something@gmail.com',
            pass: 'secret'
        }
    });
    return sendMailPromise(transporter, mailOptions);
}
```

There are some unused variables (`email`, `user_name`, `link`) and variables which seem to be global (`mailOptions`): you would need to improve that situation.

Answer (score 1):

```js
export default async function password_reset_request(email, user_name, link) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {

            var transporter = await nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: 'gmail',
                auth: {
                    user: 'something@gmail.com',
                    pass: 'secret'
                }
            });

            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
                if (error) {
                    reject();
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            reject();
        }
    });
}
```

Please check this correction.

Comment: `var transporter = await nodemailer.createTransport({`

Answer (score 0):

> Can we use resolve or reject function in more then one place?

Yes, we can there's no issue. It's similar to return different things under different conditions.

> Have you used promises correctly?

No. Why you are using async function and promise at same time? What's use of creating function async?

Just modify code to this.

```
export default function password_reset_request(email, user_name, link) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                user: 'something@gmail.com',
                pass: 'secret'
            }
        });

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
            if (error) {
                reject()
            } else {
                resolve()
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Will suggest you to read docs for any feature of JavaScript you want to use. JavaScript provide multiple functions for same functionality, we need to decide which works best for our case, in place of using all at once.

Do go through these docs [async-await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in Javascript.